# Python YouTube Video Downloader with URL

Tags: python, youtube, pytube

I used this code to download a Youtube video before 3 weeks and it worked but now when i try to run it i am getting this :

raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)

urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 410: Gone

how to fix it ?

```
from pytube import YouTube
link=input("Enter the URL link : ")
video=YouTube(link)

video.streams.get_highest_resolution().download(output_path=r'D:\YouTubevideos')

print("Download done")
```

Comment: What url was it? The 410 Gone Error is an HTTP response status code indicating that the resource requested by the client has been permanently deleted, and that the client should not expect an alternative redirection or forwarding address. I think the video was probably deleted

Comment: This the  url  :  https://youtu.be/34Na4j8AVgA

Comment: @Mushari there is bug reported for this issue couple of hours ago[HTTP Error 410: Gone](https://github.com/pytube/pytube/issues/1076)